# SQL add value into cell at specific position

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert

I have an SQL database with a table called songs which consist of a column called lyrics where
the lyrics of songs are stored in a cell. I need to format these lyrics with the format tag {BL}, so what i want is to inster {BL} after every CDATA[ and {/BL} before every ]]>. I this possible with SQL command, I tried inster or update but they don't keep the original content.

Here is an example with the before content

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<song version="1.0"><lyrics><verse label="1" type="v">
<![CDATA[ Lyrics here.]]></verse></lyrics></song>
```

And this is what i want the content to look like after.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<song version="1.0"><lyrics><verse label="1" type="v">
<![CDATA[ {BL} Lyrics here... .{/BL}]]></verse></lyrics></song>
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Column data type?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and XML processing functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)